# How to match at least two conditions in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
df1<-data.frame(A=rnorm(100,mean = 10,sd=1),B=rnorm(100,mean = 10,sd=1))
```

and 4 conditions:

```
cond1<-df1$A+1>df1$B
cond2<-df1$A+2>df1$B
cond3<-df1$A+3>df1$B
cond4<-df1$A+4>df1$B
```

If I want to match any of the condition and turn `A`to `0`, I will do:

```
df1[cond1|cond2|cond3|cond4,"A"]<-0
```

What if I want to match at least two or at least three of the conditions? Is there a easy way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way using sums.

At least two:

```
df1[(cond1+cond2+cond3)>=2,"A"]=0
```

Less than two:

```
df1[(cond1+cond2+cond3)<2,"A"]=0
```

Cond1 and at least one of cond2 or cond3:

```
df1[cond1+(cond2+cond3)>=1,"A"]=0
```

Etc.

Comment: Add `<- 0` to that :)